# Parsing JSON with backslash in the end of an string value- encountering JSON parse error

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I am having a scenario where a string value ends with the backslash (' \ '), because of which I am unable to parse it to JSON I get parse error, I tried encoding this backslash (to "\"), but since I have very large data to be converted, and lot of iterations to run through the page turns non-responsive and I feel this is not a very way to achieve the solution. Please help me with this. Thanks in Advance :)

I have already tried jQuery.parseJSON & JSON.parse

Comment: Backslash is an escape character. It escapes the following character to tell the parser not to take that following character's special meaning into account but use it literally, as is. A single backslash character needs to be escaped, too, to interpret it as a literal backslash character so it becomes ``\\``.

Comment: @marekful 18: Do we have any possible solution to ignore backslash other than replacing the value with some known value and then Parsing? Something like JavaScript encode and then Parse to JSON?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you post the original string you are trying to parse into JSON object?